# How to only show a nested UL and hide its parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a nested (sub) list, but hide the parent ULs and LIs through an "active" class so that the sub list looks like the parent list.

The list with the "active" class isn't visible because it inherits display: none from its parent.

Code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Hidden
        <ul>
            <li class="active">Visible</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: none;
}
li.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2C8qs

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't really make much sense to do this, semantically. If the contained child needs to be visible whilst the parent is not, then that tends to be a good clue that they shouldn't in fact be parent and child. Perhaps they should be siblings with a common parent?

Comment: @Klors I'm having this same problem now. Would you not say its semantic if they represent a hierarchy - in my case, chapters and subchapters and sub-subchapters etc. in some "book"? If you were then to display their "index" page you might only want to show one section of it at a time. If you disagree that an unordered list is logical here, then how would you go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add span around the hidden text (http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/2C8qs/3/) :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Hidden</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="active">Visible</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


li span, li li {
    display: none;
}
li li.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: none` hides the element and all of its children, that is final and adding `display: block` to a child won't make it visible again.

This will hide all children, except for the `.active` element:

```
ul.parent > li {
    display: none;
}

ul.parent > li.active {
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT: Oops, I misread the question. You can do something similar to the above though, if you wrap the other contents in an element.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly CSS trick : http://jsfiddle.net/2C8qs/4/

Instead of using `display none/block`, I used text-indent, like that :

```
li {
text-indent: -99999em

}
li.active {
    text-indent: 0
}
```

*Note that can only work on inline / text elements.*

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late to this question, but I've found what I would consider a nice solution and thought I'd post it here for whoever might need it in the future.

First of all, wrap all the `<li>`'s children with `<p>` (or `<div>` or anything, it doesn't matter really), but not any sub-`<ul>`'s. Then, to the child `<ul>` you want to be visible, add a class called `showing`. Example (we only want to show the SubSubThing list):

```
<ul>
<li>
    <p>Item</p>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <p>SubItem</p>
        <ul>
        <li>
            <p>SubSubItem</p>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <p>Thing</p>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <p>SubThing</p>
        <ul class="showing">
        <li>
            <p>SubSubThing1</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>SubSubThing2</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>SubSubThing3</p>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Then apply this CSS:

```
ul>li {
  list-style:none;
}

ul>li>p {
    display: none;
}

ul.showing>li>p {
    display:block;
}

/* Without removing padding and margin,
   the sublists appear way over to the right */

ul {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Now, only the `<li>`'s who are direct descendants of `ul`'s with a `showing` class will display at all. The other items in the list will use no space.

To get the sublists to show bullet points would be easy via CSS, and to show different sublists it is simple to just use jQuery to set `showing` on the appropriate `ul`.

Hope that helps.

[Obligatory JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggygL6ec/1/)

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you can't simply hide the first li and reveal the second is because the second is contained by the first — you can't reveal and element that is contained by a hidden one.

Therefore, if you put the li element within a span that you'd like to hide, it becomes easy. I've created a class-free version for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/rgpnr6mh/3/

```
<ul>
  <li><span>Hidden</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Visible</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm assuming you don't want to display the bullets:

```
ul {
  list-style-type:none
}

li span{
  display: none;
}
li li {
  display: block;
}
```